# Loading socket.io/socket.io.js into html head returning "ReferenceError: io is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on a simple socket.io project, and have hit a wall. When I added the script `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var socket = io(); </script>` into the head, I was expecting the application to recognize this, but instead I got the error message `GET http://localhost:5678/socket.io/socket.io.js` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` in my console. I am using the express framework.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'NodeIM' });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

server = http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});

module.exports = router;
```

HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>NodeIM</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">var socket = io(); </script>
      <style type="text/css"></style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>NodeIM</h1>
      <p>Welcome to NodeIM</p>
      <hr>
      <ul id="messages"></ul>
      <form id="im_form" action=""><input id="m" autocomplete="off"><button>Send</button></form>
   </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I've also tried to follow [socket.io - ReferenceError: io is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995406/socket-io-referenceerror-io-is-not-defined) and changed my src to `src="http://localhost:5678/socket.io/socket.io.js"`, but it did not fix the issue. I've also tried to use [Node.js socket.io.js not found or io not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563080/node-js-socket-io-js-not-found-or-io-not-defined), which just showed me another way of requiring socket.io, but doesn't fix the `ReferenceError` problem I am having

Comment: What version of Express are you using?  This error is likely because you haven't done the server-side initialization correctly so that the socket.io library hasn't set up the route for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Comment: I'm using Express version `4.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `/socket.io/socket.io.js` for `src` is correct. However, your setting up of the http server has a typo: `var http = require('http').Server(express);` should probably be `var http = require('http').Server(router);`.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the chat-demo on [Socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) you should put the `<script>` directly above the *closing* `</body>`-tag. Like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I see no reason why this should solve a problem any better than the code the OP is already using.  I have my client socket.io in the `<head>` section and it works just fine there.